# Is it reasonable to use static classes to manage network requests?

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, static

I have a static http request helper in ASP.NET

Is it thread safe?

Will it cause a memory leak?

Will the singleton model be a better choice?
PS: In this case, I don't need extend classes or implement interfaces.

Will this code have a bad effect on the program?

Here is the code.Thank you for your help.

```
    public static class NetUtils
    {
        private static string API_VERSION = "1.0";

        private static readonly string API_GET_TOKEN = "/gettoken.json";

        public static string Post(string api, Dictionary<string, string> mParams)
        {

            string resultStr = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                string domain = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiDomain"];
                string url = string.Format("{0}{1}", domain, api);

                string dictDataString = DictUrlEncode(mParams);
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                byte[] byteData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dictDataString);
                using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    postStream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
                }
                HttpWebResponse respponse = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = respponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader read = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
                resultStr = read.ReadToEnd();
                read.Close();
                respponse.Close();
                request.Abort();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogUtils.Log(string.Format("{0}: {1}", api, ex.ToString()));
            }
            return resultStr;
        }
```

Comment: Static methods are not a problem for multithreading. Static variables are what you have to look out for. That being said, static methods make unit testing difficult, so I'd recommend either a singleton or just a regular instanced object that your program holds on to, e.g. as a singleton-instanced injected dependency.

Comment: ^^ _"singleton-instanced injected dependency"_ <- this.

Comment: make me awake, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is preferible to use objects instead of static classes beacause of test purposes.

Assume you have this class

```
public class SomeLogic {

    public object SomeMethod() {
      ...
      NetUtils.Post("aUrl",aObject);
      ...
    }
}
```

You will never be able to create a unit test: this code will always do the http call.
Your test could fail because of network errors or server errors, and this is not what you want to achieve with a Unit Test.

In this case I would just inject the dependency (as a Singleton or not) through an interface

```
public interface INetworkUtils {
    string Post(string api, Dictionary<string, string> mParams)
}
```

so that if you need to create Unit Test you can.

If you are not going to create Tests than the solution with the static class is ok.